# Passing data from one resolver to another on the same route Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to pass data from one resolver to the other on the same route?

```
  {
    path: 'book-view/:id',
    component: BookViewComponent,
    resolve: {
      book: BookViewResolver,
      user: UserResolver
    }
  }
```

Let's say I want to pass a data (uploader_id) from the data in BookViewResolver to Make an HTTP call 
from my UserResolver.

BookViewResolver

```
 export class BookViewResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.bookService.getBook(route.params['id']);
  }
}
```

UserResolver

```
 export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.getUser(uploader_id from BookViewResolver);
  }
}
```

Before the data gets to the final component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible but I suggest you use 1 resolver containing both Book and AuthService and use `RxJS's switchMap` for it if ever these services emits and Observable.

---

**UPDATE for Angular~15**

**`BookViewResolver`**

```
export const bookViewResolver: ResolveFn<any> =
(
   route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
   state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<any> => {
     const bookService = inject(BookService);
     const authService = inject(AuthService);

     // After the BookService fetches its corresponding data, you can pass
     // its response to the next call which is the authService and pass the 
     // uploaderId from the response data itself
     return this.bookService
       .getBook(id)
       .pipe(switchMap(data => this.authService.getUser(data.uploaderId)))
};
```

**`Router`**

```
{
   path: 'book-view/:id',
   component: BookViewComponent,
   resolve: {
     book: bookViewResolver
   } 
}
```

**More Info on `ResolveFn`:**

- https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn

Comment: Please update this answer.  implementing Resolve<any> is deprecated now